# Simple inquiry about how conditionals are executed C++

Tags: c++

Simple yes-or-no question:

I have a chunk of code that is like

```
while (_attributeChars.find_first_of(*it++) != std::string::npos)
```

and I'm wondering if `it` will still be incremented `when _attributeChars.find_first_of(*it) != std::string::npos` is `false`. That is, while it increment even on the last evaluation of the `while` loop?

Comment: This could have been easily answered by stepping through with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

For your program to know if it should continue or stop the loop, it has to evaluate the expression inside, which means that in this case `*it++` will always be executed.

Another thing you should be aware of, which is related to your question, is the difference between `++x` and `x++`. The first form returns the new value of x while the second form returns the old one.

You can learn more about it here: http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4410601/Pre-increment-or-post-increment-in-C-C-

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `it` will always be incremented when this conditional is evaluated, because the expression `it++` must be evaluated each time.  If an expression with side-effects is evaluated, those side-effects will be observed.

---

There are cases when it wouldn't be, but that's only when using a short-circuiting boolean operator, which you are not using here.  For example:

```
while (something() && it++)
```

In this case `it` would not be incremented if `something()` evaluated to false, because the `&&` operator short-circuits if the right operand is irrelevant to the result. The `||` and `?:` operators also short-circuit.

- `a && b`: `b` is not evaluated when `a` is false.
- `a || b`: `b` is not evaluated when `a` is true.
- `a ? b : c`: If `a` is true then only `b` is evaluated, otherwise only `c` is evaluated.

If an expression is not evaluated then any side-effects it has (such as increment/decrement or function calls) will not be performed.

Comment: ...unless they're overloaded boolean operators for user-defined types... :-/

Comment: I don't see how short-circuiting is even relevant to the question.

Comment: @Alex I'm showing one circumstance in which side-effects in an expression will not happen, as a counterexample to this particular situation. Sometimes knowing when side-effects don't happen will help illustrate why they do -- in this case because of the absence of any operator that does short-circuiting.

Comment: @TonyD I don't follow. In `a && b` where both are user-defined types with an `operator bool()`, if `a` converts to false, `b` still isn't evaluated... http://ideone.com/zrHWkh

Comment: @cdhowie I think Tony D meant when overloading the `&& operator`. http://ideone.com/XG9bxn

Comment: Oh, well, yes if you are overloading operators then you are changing their behavior and semantics. No surprises there. We don't expect people to provide a disclaimer that "`&&` is boolean 'and' ... unless there is a user-defined operator that makes it do something else."

Comment: (Thanks Alex - beat me to explaining)... @cdhowie - I'd hazard that inhibiting short circuit evaluation *in the calling context* is more noteworthy than the usual "do[ing] something else" *inside* the function that's obvious for all user-defined operators; but anyway, these comments document it... if my first comment didn't jog a reader's memory or it was new to them, I'm sure Alex's suffices.  I only mentioned it because you seemed determined to be thorough on this particular tangent to the question.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD Fair point. It's not something I usually consider because it's not something I have seen used widely in the field. (In fact, I don't think I ever have, and our C++ codebase here is in the tens-of-millions of lines!)

Comment: @cdhowie Fair enough - it's not everyday application-level stuff.  Many consider it best practice to avoid it unless there's a compelling need, precisely because people may be surprised by the lack of short circuit evaluation.  But it does crop up in specialised code - e.g. the [boost spirit sequential or parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/sequential_or.html).